# Stop camera from moving on x axis

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, scripting, perspectivecamera

So I have a rocket (player) that is flying up on the Y axis. I have a camera with this script following the rocket:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject player;
private Vector3 offset;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    offset = transform.position;
}



// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () 
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
}
```

How can I stop the camera from moving on the x axis? I only want it to follow the rocket upwards on the Y axis. I tried adding a rigid body and blocking the X axis there but that didn't work. Any ideas how to do this in script? Thank you!

P.S. I'm kinda new to scripting, please tell me how to implement the extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a simple way to lock your camera into just one axis would be to change the code you provided above to this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject player;
private Vector3 offset;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    offset = transform.position;
}



// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () 
{
    transform.position = new Vector(
    offset.x, player.transform.position.y + offset.y,
    offset.z);
}
}
```

This should make the camera only go up/down along with the rocket, but not move on either the x or z axis. If this isn't exactly what you were trying to achieve, leave a comment and I'll take a look

Comment: Great, that works! Found a bug in your code, in the last 5 lines, you wrote new Vector. You need new Vector3 in Unity :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RigidBody isn't helping you because locking the axis in RigidBody only ignores movement that is called by Unity's physics, you could use AddForce if you want to handle it by RigidBody but no point for doing all that. Easiest way is just to override X value like this:

```
Vector3 newPosition = player.transform.position + offset;
newPosition.x = 0;
transform.position = newPosition;
```

This calculates the new position and then just sets the X to zero (or any other value you want) and then sets that vector as the position.